# nodejs request module check for response status before pipe into file

Tags: node.js

I am currently using "request" module to download some files.

The code looks like

```
function download(url, fileName, path) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        request({url: url})
        .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(path))
        .on("close", function() {
            log.d("File %s downloaded to path %s", fileName, path);
            resolve(info);
        })
        .on("error", reject);
    });
}
```

Now, I notice that even when the URL returns a 404 NOT FOUND. Somehow the request module still manages to pipe out something and a file with 1 kb is stored.

What can I do to intercept the status code, maybe check that it is less than 400. Before piping it to file?

I look up their github, couldn't find an example.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Which module is 'request' from?

Comment: Hmmm,  I see  `.on('response', function(response) { console.log(response.statusCode) ...` -  https://github.com/request/request#streaming. It's unbelievable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK basically i need to give the request() a call back and reject on statusCode >= 400